# Issue while getting sheets & slides Editor event object in Google Workspace Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am making a Google Workspace Add-on in which I want to get sheet object such as

```
"sheets": {
            "addonHasFileScopePermission": true,
            "id":"A_24Q3CDA23112312ED52",
            "title":"How to get started with Sheets"
          },
```

But I am not getting sheets object when I am trying it with docs, I am only able to get docs object.
Here is a sample event object for docs and sheets as below:

```
//In case of docs, I am getting docs object with details title, id etc. For docs

{ clientPlatform: 'web',
  docs: 
   { title: 'How to get started with Docs',
     id: 'A_24Q3CDA23112312ED52sdsff',
     addonHasFileScopePermission: true },
  hostApp: 'docs',
  userCountry: 'GB',
  commonEventObject: 
   { userLocale: 'en-GB',
     platform: 'WEB',
     hostApp: 'DOCS',
     timeZone: { id: 'Asia/Kolkata', offset: 19800000 } },
  userLocale: 'en',
  userTimezone: { offSet: '19800000', id: 'Asia/Kolkata' } }
      
//But in Case of Sheets and Slides, I am not getting  objects sheets or slides with details title, id etc. For Sheets  
  

{ clientPlatform: 'web',
  userLocale: 'en',
  hostApp: 'sheets',
  userCountry: 'GB',
  userTimezone: { offSet: '19800000', id: 'Asia/Kolkata' },
  commonEventObject: 
   { hostApp: 'SHEETS',
     platform: 'WEB',
     userLocale: 'en-GB',
     timeZone: { id: 'Asia/Kolkata', offset: 19800000 } } }
```

Here is the my add-on manifest file

```
{
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly"
                 ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Add_on",
      "logoUrl": "{my logo url}",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDriveHomePageOpen"
      },
    },
    "drive": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDriveHomePageOpen",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
      }
    },
    "docs": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDocsHomepage"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGrantedEditors"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onSheetsHomepage"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGrantedEditors"
      }
    },
    "slides": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onSlidesHomepage"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGrantedEditors"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And Sample code is as below:

```
function onDocsHomepage(e) {
  console.info(e);
  return createAddOnView(e);
}

function onSheetsHomepage(e) {
  console.info(e);
  return createAddOnView(e);
}

function onSlidesHomepage(e) {
  console.info(e);
  return createAddOnView(e);
}

function createAddOnView(e) {
  var docsEventObject;
  if(e['hostApp'] == 'docs'){
   docsEventObject = e['docs'];
  }
  if(e['hostApp'] == 'sheets'){
    docsEventObject = e['sheets'];
  }
  if(e['hostApp'] == 'slides'){
    docsEventObject = e['slides'];
  }
  var builder =  CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection();
  if (docsEventObject!=null && docsEventObject['addonHasFileScopePermission']!=null) {
    cardSection.setHeader(docsEventObject['title']);
    // This add-on uses the recommended, limited-permission `drive.file`
    // scope to get granular per-file access permissions.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth
    // If the add-on has access permission, read and display its quota.
    cardSection.addWidget(
      CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("File Id: " + docsEventObject['id']));
  } else {
    // If the add-on does not have access permission, add a button that
    // allows the user to provide that permission on a per-file basis.
    cardSection.addWidget(
      CardService.newTextParagraph()
      .setText( "The add-on needs permission to access this file." ));

    var buttonAction = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName("onRequestFileScopeButtonClicked");

    var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("Request permission")
      .setOnClickAction(buttonAction);
    cardSection.addWidget(button);
  }
  return builder.addSection(cardSection).build();
}

function onRequestFileScopeButtonClicked(e) {
  return CardService.newEditorFileScopeActionResponseBuilder()
      .requestFileScopeForActiveDocument().build();
}

function onFileScopeGrantedEditors(e){
  console.info("after granting item");
  console.info(e);
  return createAddOnView(e);
}
```

In the above code, I am only able to get docs object and not able to get sheets & slides objects after grating access of files in add-on.

As per documentation here is a sample Editor event object(for sheets): https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/gsao/building-editor-interfaces#event_objects
and a sample code of request file access for current document:https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/gsao/editor-actions#request_file_access_for_current_document

What is the issue? why I am not getting the objects for sheets and slides? Only given example works for docs not for sheets and slides.

Comment: Do you get an event object at all? What is its value if you do?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Yes I am getting event object and I already shared for docs as well sheets. Please look at my shared sample event object in above Query.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the script so I can test the deployment?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo here: https://script.google.com/d/1aGENCFoXlgzeITd5EjMSb2h4vqFdmD-kgSXkUn1C1vtDBYY0FE_puBQE/edit?usp=sharing is sample code script in App Script, You can make a copy and test it.

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Sheets information not returned from Workspace Editor add-on event object](https://issuetracker.google.com/187173685)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

Comment: For the above issue, I have already opened a case on Google's Issue Tracker that is : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186945184

Comment: Is this issue fixed? I am facing the same one.

Comment: @DivyaDev If you're still seeing the behaviour then I would hazard a guess that it hasn't been fixed.

Comment: @Rafa it got fixed yesterday night around 8.00. I was working, the object didn’t have the sheet ID. And, all of a sudden it started appearing. I think that was when Google must have released a fix, or rolled back one of their fixes that caused the issue. Now, the ID is seen across domains, after the file scope is granted.